# Use jquery to animate the font size of a span without moving the rest of the line

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a simple line that use the class .glyphicon-heart of bootstrap to put a heart in the middle of the text:

```
<p>Some text <span class="glyphicon-heart"></span></p>
```

My code below "pulses" the heart, animating it to increase its size and reducing later:

```
$('.glyphicon-heart').animate({fontSize: '200%'}).animate({fontSize: '100%'});
```

The problem is that when I animate it, the rest of the line moves. I believe it is because the maximum line height changes when the span font size is increased.

Can I make this animation without moving the rest of the line, i.e., without, changing the maximum line-height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also animate the line-height of the paragraph tag to go with it. In this fiddle I added a line-height of 20px to the p tag, so change it to whatever yours is. I animated to 0px then back to 20px;

http://jsfiddle.net/z9BMF/

`<p style="line-height:20px;line-height:20px;">Some text <span class="glyphicon-heart">LARGER</span></p>`

`$('.glyphicon-heart').animate({fontSize: '200%', lineHeight: '0px'}).animate({fontSize: '100%', lineHeight:'20px'});`

Comment: Almost there. It still moved the line, but I did a little modification and it almost worked. Instead of using 0 as the line height, I've saved the original value and set it. This worked fine: var lineHeightOriginal = el.css('lineHeight');  el.animate({fontSize: '200%', lineHeight: lineHeightOriginal}); The problem was when I tried to animate to a smaller font size of 80%. The line moved decreasing the distance from the line above.